# When download via aab, does it download only changes?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

as i know, the "**Incremental Build**" is that builds only the change points by comparing the past and the present.

Android AAB is also modularized, so I think there is a similar system.

When I get the latest update from PlayStore,
I wonder it download whole files, Or only changes between **Local version and Lastest version**.